# Python-processed Avro formatted data sent through a Apache Kafka does not yield same output when dezerialized in Apache Camel/Java processor

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, avro, binary-data

I am running a Kafka broker where I push messages to via a Python program. For efficient data exhchange I use Apache Avro format. At the Kafka broker, the message is picked up by a Camel route with processor. In this processor I want to de-serialize the message and finally want to push data to an InfluxDB.

The process mechanics work, but in the Camel route I do not get the data out I put in. On the Python side
I create a dictionary:

```
testDict = dict()
testDict['name'] = 'avroTest'
testDict['double_one'] = 1.2345
testDict['double_two'] = 1.23
testDict['double_three'] = 2.345
testDict['time_stamp'] = long(time.time() * 1000000000)
```

The corresponding Avro schema on Python side looks like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "my.namespace",
  "name": "myRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name",         "type": "string"},
    {"name": "double_one",   "type": "double"},
    {"name": "double_two",   "type": "double"},
    {"name": "double_three", "type": "double"},
    {"name": "time_stamp",   "type": "long"}
  ]
}
```

The Python code for sending the avro-formatted message to Kafka look like this:

```
def sendAvroFormattedMessage(self, dataDict: dict, topic_id: str, schemaDefinition: str) \
        -> FutureRecordMetadata:
    """
    Method for sending message to kafka broker in the avro binary format
    :param dataDict: data dictionary containing message data
    :param topic_id: the Kafka topic to send message to
    :param schemaDefinition: JSON schema definition
    :return: FurtureRecordMetadata
    """
    schema = avro.schema.parse(schemaDefinition)
    writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)
    bytes_stream = io.BytesIO()
    encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_stream)
    writer.write(dataDict, encoder)
    raw_bytes = bytes_stream.getvalue()

    messageBrokerWriterConnection = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=<connectionUrl>, client_id='testLogger')
    
    result = messageBrokerWriterConnection.send(topic=topic_id, value=raw_bytes, key='AVRO_FORMAT'.encode('UTF-8'))
    return result
```

The message arrives as expected at the broker, is picked up by camel and processed by the following JAVA code:

```
from(kafkaEndpoint) //
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Long kafkaInboundTime = Long
                            .parseLong(exchange.getIn().getHeader("kafka.TIMESTAMP").toString());
                    if (exchange.getIn().getHeader("kafka.KEY") != null) {

                        BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get()
                                .binaryDecoder(exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class), null);

                        SpecificDatumReader<Record> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(avroSchema);

                        System.out.println(datumReader.read(null, decoder).toString());
                    }
                }) //
                .to(influxdbEndpoint);
```

With `avroSchema` currently hard coded in the constructor of my class as follows:

```
avroSchema = SchemaBuilder.record("myRecord") //
                .namespace("my.namespace") //
                .fields() //
                .requiredString("name") //
                .requiredDouble("double_one") //
                .requiredDouble("double_two") //
                .requiredDouble("double_three") //
                .requiredLong("time_stamp") //  
                .endRecord();
```

The output of `System.out.println` is

```
{"name": "avroTest", "double_one": 6.803527358993313E-220, "double_two": -0.9919128115125185, "double_three": -0.9775074719163893, "time_stamp": 20}
```

Obviously, something goes wrong, but I don't know what. Any help appreciated.

**Update 1**
As the Python code is running on an Intel/Window machine, Kafka (In a VM) and the Java code on Linux machines with unknown architecture, could this effect be caused by different endian-ness of the systems?

**Update 1.1** Endian-ness can be excluded. Checked on both sides, both were 'little'

**Update 2**
As a check I changed the schema definition to string type for all fields. With this definition, values and keys are transferred correctly - Python input and Java/Camel output are the same.

**Update 3**
The camel rout producer endpoint to Kafka does not have any special features such as deserializers, etc.:

```
"kafka:myTopicName?brokers=host:9092&clientId=myClientID&autoOffsetReset=earliest"
```

Comment: Are you able to get the raw bytes on the Python side before they are sent to Kafka and then again on the Java side before they are deserialized? If they are different, then something is happening in the middle that is causing the data to change. If they are the same and you can post the bytes then it should be possible to figure out which side is not doing the serialization/deserialization correctly.

Comment: I have a deserializer on Python side checking the data sent to Kafka. This check yields the same as the input.

Comment: ... but besides that - di you think my code is OK?

Comment: The consistency check looks like this:

`# for data conistency testing
        bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
        decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
        reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
        user1 = reader.read(decoder)
        #user2 = reader.read(decoder)

        print(user1)`

Comment: I think that looks right for a consistency check. But are you doing this check on the data being sent to kafka or is this being done after kafka has processed the message? If this check is before kafka has processed the message, we still don't know if somehow the message is getting changed within kafka.

Comment: The check is performed directly after the second last line of Python code `result = messageBrokerWriterConnection.send(topic=topic_id, value=raw_bytes, key='AVRO_FORMAT'.encode('UTF-8')), before the `return result`. I skipped this to make the code in the question more dense

Comment: Hmmm... well I think I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using the Confluent Schema Registry here? In other words, why not use `confluent-kafka` which has an Avro serializer? Then use the respective Java Avro deserializer? Also, don't need a consumer, really https://docs.lenses.io/4.1/integrations/connectors/stream-reactor/sinks/influxsinkconnector/

Comment: @OneCricketeer: first and foremost of all the reason why I do not use Confluent registry is that I am a beginner in this. But aside from that I do not see a technical reason why this shouldn‘t work without Schema Registry; it is only a tool to keep the Schemas at a central place to ease maintenance of the stack - right? About the docs.lenses.it/.. I need to check what this is.

Comment: Confluent maintains serializers for the clients as well, which seems to be part of the issue here. Otherwise, maybe try python's fastavro library instead or a different version of the Java Avro library

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I don't know why, but in our organization, I cannot use depecencies to Confluent artifacts - they don't import.

Comment: I assume you mean in Java? Those aren't in maven central, so you need to add the Confluent maven repo to your build... The Python ones should import fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The following Python code produces the desired output into Kafka:

```
def sendAvroFormattedMessage(self, dataDict: dict, topic_id: MessageBrokerQueue, schemaDefinition: str) \
        -> FutureRecordMetadata:
    """
    Method for sending message to kafka broker in the avro binary format
    :param dataDict: data dictionary containing message data
    :param topic_id: the Kafka topic to send message to
    :param schemaDefinition: JSON schema definition
    :return: None
    """
    schema = avro.schema.parse(schemaDefinition)

    bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
    encoder = BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
    writer = DatumWriter(schema)
    writer.write(dataDict, encoder)
    raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()

    self._messageBrokerWriterConnection = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self._connectionUrl)

    try:
        # NOTE: I use the 'AVRO' key to separate avro formatted messages from others 
        result = self._messageBrokerWriterConnection.send(topic=topic_id, value=raw_bytes, key='AVRO'.encode('UTF-8'))
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    self._messageBrokerWriterConnection.flush()
```

Key to the solution was adding the `valueDeserializer=...` to the end point definition on the Apache Camel side:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;

 ...

TEST_QUEUE("kafka:topic_id?brokers=host:port&clientId=whatever&valueDeserializer=" + ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
```

The Apache camel route code including the conversion to InfluxDB point can then be written like this:

```
@Component
public class Route_TEST_QUEUE extends RouteBuilder {

   Schema avroSchema = null;

   private Route_TEST_QUEUE() {
       avroSchema = SchemaBuilder //
             .record("ElectronCoolerCryoMessage") //       
             .namespace("de.gsi.fcc.applications.data.loggers.avro.messages") //
            .fields() //
            .requiredString("name") //
            .requiredDouble("double_one") //
            .requiredDouble("double_two") //
            .requiredDouble("double_three") //
            .requiredLong("time_stamp") // 
            .endRecord();
    }

    private String fromEndpoint = TEST_QUEUE.definitionString();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(fromEndpoint) //
                .process(messagePayload -> {        
                    byte[] data = messagePayload.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
                    BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);
                    SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(avroSchema);
                    GenericRecord record = datumReader.read(null, decoder);

                    try {
                        Point.Builder influxPoint = Point
                            .measurement(record.get("name").toString());
                        long acqStamp = 0L;
                        if (record.hasField("time_stamp") && (long) record.get("time_stamp") > 0L) {
                            acqStamp = (long) record.get("time_stamp");
                        } else {
                            acqStamp = Long.parseLong(messagePayload.getIn().getHeader("kafka.TIMESTAMP").toString());
                        }

                        influxPoint.time(acqStamp, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

                        Map<String, Object> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();

                        avroSchema.getFields().stream() //
                                .filter(field ->    !field.name().equals("keyFieldname")) //
                                .forEach(field -> {
                                     Object value = record.get(field.name());
                                    fieldMap.put(field.name().toString(), value);
                                });

                        influxPoint.fields(fieldMap);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         MessageLogger.logError(e);
                    }
                }) //
                .to(...InfluxEndpoint...) //
                .onException(Exception.class) //
                .useOriginalMessage() //
                .handled(true) //
                .to("stream:out");
        }
    }
}
```

This works for my purposes - no confluent, only kafka.